How to specify audio input to FFplay?
I find FFplay a very simple and useful program to display the video from my capture device (MS2109) with:
ffplay  -f v4l2  -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 

But that doesn't give me audio. In a different context I use FFmpeg to capture the video and audio to a mkv file with the audio input specified as -f alsa hw:1. Adding this to the ffplay command just gives the error

Argument hw:1 provided as input filename, but /dev/video0 was already specified.

How do I get audio input from the capture device with FFplay?

I suggest to just pipe from ffmpeg to ffplay

As Gyan commented, we nay pipe from FFmpeg to FFplay:
ffmpeg -i -f v4l2 -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i hw:1 -c copy -f nut pipe: | ffplay -f nut -i pipe:

There are some tricks for using FFplay with two input sources, but I think there is no option for using video source and audio source simultaneously.
Capturing the input sources and piping to FFplay may solve the issue.

ffmpeg -i -f v4l2 -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 - Capture the video input (source).
-f alsa -i hw:1 - Capture the audio input (source).
-c copy - don't re-encode the input streams (keep the original codecs).
-f nut - "Mux" the video and audio to NUT container. NUT format is recommended, because it accepts almost any codec (without re-encoding).
pipe: - Select stdout as output.
| ffplay -f nut -i pipe: - pass stdout of FFmpeg to stdin input of FFplay. The | applies "pipe" operator. -f nut tels FFplay to expect NUT format, and -i pipe, tels FFplay to play the input from the stdin pipe.


Note:
I couldn't test my answer, with alsa input.
In case it's not working, try -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le instead of -c copy.

Had some difficulty at first, but then I took the exact ffmpeg command line I was using for capture, and added  "-f nut pipe: | ffplay -f nut -i pipe:" and that worked! Thanks!!
